# Lost reference: Kähler gravity in six dimensions and three dimensional $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ Chern-Simons theory

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, mathematics, topological-field-theory

I've noticed that several references take for a fact that by studying [Kähler gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9410011#:%7E:text=It%20describes%20deformations%20of%20K%C3%A4hler,theory%20for%20supersymmetric%20quantum%20mechanics.) on a Calabi-Yau threefold one can demostrate that any lagrangian submanifold embedded in the threefold posees three dimensional $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ [Chern Simons theory](https://inspirehep.net/literature/264816) as its worldvolume theory.

For an example of a paper were this is explicitly stated, see the first paragraph on page 28 of [Quantum Foam and Topological Strings](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312022), this paper remits to its reference [22] for a proof; the problem is that this reference was never published, as far I know.

**Question one:** Does anyone know of any reference with a proof of this fact?

I've thought that maybe nobody needs a proof because the statement is obvious. Unfortunately, that's not my case. I can figure out that some relationship exist because some supersymmetric extensions of three dimensional gravity compute the Casson invariant of its three dimensional target space (see the last section of [this](https://inspirehep.net/literature/276667) paper), but the Casson invariant is related to tree level topological string B-model and not with Kähler gravity which is the tree level A-model theory. So I'm confused.

**Question two:** Does anyone know an intuitive picture of why the statement I'm hoping to understand is true?

Any reference, parallel reading suggestion or comment is helpful.